# missing checkbox value after validation in laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a form for offices registration,with tree field:caption,top office and status that for active or inactive ,i wand to store status in database by 0 and 1 value,in my blade :

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="1">
 <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Is Active?</label>
```

in request file only roles are for caption and top_office_id:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "caption" => "required|between:3,40",
            "top_office_id" => "nullable"
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            "caption.required" => "required value ",
            "caption.between" => "value must between 3 and 20 charachter",

        ];
    }
```

in model file :

```
protected $primaryKey='office_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'caption',
        'top_office_id',
        'status'
    ];
```

and in service file :

```
public function create($data)
    {
        return Office::create($data);
    }

    public function update($office, $data)
    {
        return $office->update($data);
    }
```

and finally in controller:

```
public function store(OfficeRequseStore $request, OfficeService $service)
    {   
        dd($request->all());
        
        $attributes = $request->validated();
        
        dd($attributes);

        $office = $service->create($attributes);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

After execution, if we fill all tags in form and check status checkbox, then by enabling first dd in controller it will display values ​​for all fields and status field will display 1 but if value of first dd disable and enable the second dd, the status field is missing and does not show any value, what happened to the status field after validation? What is the method to fix and receive the status file and store in database?

Comment: the `status` input is not part of your validation ... `validated` **only** returns the fields that were **validated**

Comment: So I have to do a mandatory validation for the checkbox?How to do this؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `validated` method only passes the attributes that you define on your validation rules.

assume you have this payload below

```
{
    "caption": "Whatever"
    "top_office_id": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "something": "weird",
    "should_not": "beIncluded" 
}
```

then you have this

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'caption' => 'required|between:3,40',
    'top_office_id' => 'nullable'
]);
```

`$validated` will only have this array

```
[ 
    'caption' => 'Whatever',
    'top_office_id' => 1
]
```

So, all the data you need must be define on your validation rule.

Or you can just use the request attributes after the validation

```
//run the validation, will throw back an error if fail
$request->validate([
    'caption' => 'required|between:3,40',
    'top_office_id' => 'nullable'
]);
```

then grab the fields you need from the payload after the validation on some fields.

```
$attributes = $request->only(['caption', 'top_office_id', 'status']);

//$attributes will contain 
[ 
    'caption' => 'Whatever',
    'top_office_id' => 1,
    'status' => 1
]
```